# Assign key dynamic inside foreach

Tags: javascript

```
const amountForQtyCost = [{key: "Labour Cost", value: 550}, {key: "Material Cost", value: 249}];
const requestingCost = [{key: "Labour Cost", value: 560}, {key: "Material Cost", value: 250}];
```

code to calculate the difference

```
amountForQtyCost.forEach(amount => {
        requestingCost.forEach(requestAmount => {
          if(amount.key === requestAmount.key) {
            let adjustedAmount = amount.value - requestAmount.value;
            let data = { requestAmount.key: +adjustedAmount }; // error in this line how to assign key ?
            newOutput.push(data);
          }
        });
      });
```

Expected output

```
[{key: "Labour Cost", value: 10}, {key: "Material Cost", value: 1}]
```

how to assign key ? What am i making wrong here

Comment: If your error was fixed, your code would produce objects of the form `{"Labour Cost": 10}`, is that what you're after, or is `{key: "Labour Cost", value: 10}` (like in your expected result) what you're after?

Comment: based on your expected output, you should be using `let data = {key: requestAmount.key, value: adjustedAmount}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use abs() for a positive value.

```
var newOutput = [];
amountForQtyCost.forEach(amount => {
        requestingCost.forEach(requestAmount => {
          if(amount.key === requestAmount.key) {
            let data =  {
                  key: amount.key,
                  value: amount.value - requestAmount.value
                  };
            newOutput.push(data);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: You could remove the **debugger** and use <> on the answer for a live demonstration.